# How to do selenium javascript code injection at the time of rendering UI?

Tags: selenium

I am writing automation for one of my application. I need to modulate an element value at the time of rendering the UI page. Is it possible to do in Selenium? I tried using JavascriptExecutor and WebDriver but it is not helping. Basically I need something which can server similar to debug in Developer Tools where I can stop at a specific point and change a variable value and proceed further.

Comment: This is a hidden element in UI which gets populated at the init stage of page rendering

Comment: Selenium does not allow doing so. You should mock the service that provides the data to your UI. For example you can use proxy that would return needed values for certain requests and bind your webdriver with that proxy.

Comment: @AlexeyR. Is there any other way as mocking that  service will be very tedious task if it has quite complex response

Comment: Why cant you change the element after UI has been loaded?

Comment: actually that element has the cascading effect on rendering of UI page. So there is no point me changing the element value after completing the page rendering. Based on the value of that element, different type of search versions gets rendered.